insert statement ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
This is the code:
INSERT INTO Assignment (AssignmentID, EmployeeID, TaskID, StartDate, EndDate) 
VALUES   
    (1, 27, 1, '2018-03-01', '2018-03-06'), 
    (2, 10, 2, '2018-03-01', '2018-03-06'), 
    (3, 12, 3, '2018-03-01', '2018-03-06'),  
    (4, 12, 4, '2018-03-11', '2018-03-14'),  
    (5, 10, 5, '2018-03-11', NULL),  
    (6, 7, 6, '2018-03-11', NULL),  
    (7, 8, 7, '2018-03-11', NULL),  
    (8, 28, 8, '2018-03-15', '2018-03-19'),  
    (9, 16, 9, '2018-03-21', NULL),  
    (10, 17, 10, '2018-03-21', NULL), 
    (11, 15, 11, '2018-03-21', NULL),  
    (12, 28, 12, '2018-03-21', NULL), 
    (13, 22, 13, '2018-03-25', NULL);

Help I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it because it looks perfectly fine but I still get the error:

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Added semicolon it didn't work

I believe Oracle doesn't support this "multiple tuples" approach - you need to use INSERT INTO table (list-of-columns) VALUES (list-of-values) for each individual tuple of data

Oracle 23c - er, I mean Oracle 23ai - does now support this syntax, but earlier versions do not.
